# Custom MembershipProvider in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a starting to learn about MVC4. As first steps, I need to perform a login since a custom database with just three roles in the database.

Is it realy necessary to implement a custom membership provider? I'm question this because I was reading this post and he's doing another way: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-membership-with-mvc4

I just need to get users from a custom database and determine the role.

To determine the rule, is a quite simple. I've got two tables called Students and Teachers. Each one has its Id as is loggin Id, and the common property password.

```
if (db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentId == x && x.Password == y) return "student"
if (db.Teachers.Where(x => x.TeacherId == x && x.Password == y) return "teacher"

// does not exist
```

Can you orient me about how to implement this features in ASP.NET?

Comment: You can extend the built in `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` to work with your custom database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **NOTE: Below may not be applicable for .NET Core or ASP.NET Core**

Before you start your research, note that membership and role management has been changed in ASP.NET MVC4. (if you're using 'Internet Application' template from Visual Studio)

Please read Jon Galloway's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) about what has changed.

New `Simple Membership Provider` is designed to be extended and overcome issues in the old membership and role management system (which is still supported as it is a part of ASP.NET)

Both implementations support role management, and you're free to select either implementation, or roll your own. There are arguments on which is better, and some developers prefer implementing their own, because of the limitations of both. (I won't go into details, as it can get biased)

Here's a tutorial to get you started. [[Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7)].. **Please note that tutorial explains the old membership system, and not the new SimpleMembership/WebSecurity method.**

**UPDATE**

Just when you think you have enough authentication frameworks, Microsoft has announced [**OWIN** - *Open Web Interface for .NET*](http://owin.org/).

OWIN is a set of interfaces for .NET which are open and pluggable, and this includes authentication. Please refer to this post [[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx)] on how to use MVC 5 OWIN Forms Authentication.